# How to return an object multiple times in Python?

Tags: python

I have a problem when doing an exception handling in a Python class.
My class structure is like:

```py
class base():
    def func():
        try:
            # some codes to deal with requests headers in here
            requests.get('...', timeout=0.1)
            return something
        except:
            # So when timeout in request occurs, func() will return 'Error'
            return 'Error'

    def A():
        func()

    def B():
        func()
    # there are about 10 functions that have called func().

    def index():
        reply = A()
        reply = B()
        # and A() B() functions are called here.
        return reply
```

My question is, is there a way to return an `'Error'` to index function directly, instead of doing exception handling every time when calling it? That is, change func() only, and it has to return 2 times(func() -> A() -> index()), so `reply` in index function will be `'Error'`.

Comment: Is the code in the `func()` that `returns 'Error'` independent of `A()` and `B()`?

Comment: No. ```func()``` has only two ```return```, one is normal response and the other is ```'Error'```, I return ```'Error'```only if a response timeout occurs.

Comment: Look for the Timeout class here: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/4ecd74693f65821a96180af2859c13560bf84560/requests/exceptions.py#L46

Comment: @Maezear, added that in my answer below, see if it helps?

Comment: @DirtyBit Thanks for your help, I'm trying to implement it now.

Comment: I'm sorry that it seems not the solution. It will just return the err message to A() or B() function, but what I expect is it will return to index() function directly, a bit like do a if/else every time calling it. (if func(): return blablabla else: return 'Error') but do it in func(). Or did I misunderstand your solution?

Comment: why don't you check for the message in `A()` or `B()` and see if it is error return it to the `index()` method accordingly?

Comment: Well, because I have 10 more functions calling func() now; furthermore, it will have more functions use func() in the future. That why I'm looking for a way to solve it directly in func() now.

Comment: That's what exceptions are for. Use them, instead of trying to work around them. If `func` doesn't know how to handle an exception. it shouldn't try. Ditto `A` and `B` and `index`. `try: action() except : return 'Error'` is *nonsense*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
def func():
  try:
     # the area may raise excetion
     pass
  except Exception1:
     # anything you like
     return 'error'
  except Exception2:
     # anything you like
     return 'error'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def test(a = 1):
  try:
     if a:
         raise Exception
     else:
         return a+10
  except:
     return "error"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`requests.Timeout`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/4ecd74693f65821a96180af2859c13560bf84560/requests/exceptions.py#L46)

```
def func():
    try:
        # some codes to deal with requests headers in here
        rq = requests.get('...', timeout=0.1)
        return 'something'
    except requests.Timeout as err:
        # So when timeout in request occurs, func() will return 'Error'
        return ('Error {}'.format(err))
```